# Django does not output results to the table

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm trying to pass values from the database to tables to the Django server. 
In the First case, all data is displayed perfectly. 
But the second table remains empty for some reason I don't understand. 
What could be the reason?

**Views.py**

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
    import sqlite3 as lite
    import os

def csv_simple_read(request):
     path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
     file = lite.connect("D:/clear/VM1/chat.db")
     cure = file.cursor()
     cure.execute(
         "SELECT chat_identifier, datetime(date/1000000000 + 978307200,'unixepoch','localtime'), case when [error]=0 then 'Send' when [error]=1 then 'Not Send' end FROM chat INNER JOIN message ON chat.ROWID = message.ROWID ORDER BY date DESC")
     rows = cure.fetchall()
     resultlist = []
     for row in rows:
         salam = (list([row[d:d + 1] for d in range(0, len(row), 1)]))
         resultdict = {}
         resultdict['name'] = salam[0]
         resultdict['date'] = salam[1]
         resultdict['status'] = salam[2]
         resultlist.append(resultdict)
     return render(request, "blog/index.html", {'results': resultlist})

     file2 = lite.connect("D:/clear2/VM2/chat.db")
     cure2 = file2.cursor()
     cure2.execute(
         "SELECT chat_identifier, datetime(date/1000000000 + 978307200,'unixepoch','localtime'), case when [error]=0 then 'Send' when [error]=1 then 'Not Send' end FROM chat INNER JOIN message ON chat.ROWID = message.ROWID ORDER BY date DESC")
     rows2 = cure2.fetchall()
     resultlist2 = []
     for row in rows2:
         salam2 = (list([row[d:d + 1] for d in range(0, len(row), 1)]))
         resultdict2 = {}
         resultdict2['name2'] = salam2[0]
         resultdict2['date2'] = salam2[1]
         resultdict2['status2'] = salam2[2]
         resultlist2.append(resultdict2)
     return render(request, "blog/index.html", {'results2': resultlist2})
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.csv_simple_read, name='csv_simple_read'),
    path('', views.csv_simple_read2, name='csv_simple_read2'), #??????
]
```

Comment: How do you want to reach that view if you give it the same url as the first one?

Comment: is it? I gave them different names? Can you poke me please, where is my mistake? I am very weak in this. @dirkgroten

Comment: Both are the same url `''`, ie. you top-level url (e.g. `localhost:8000/`). They are different pages, so they should have a different url.

Comment: Weird. I don't understand how to fix this. Did on examples and templates, in which this was not. 
What can I do to make these 2 databases from different folders appear on the same page? @dirkgroten

Comment: Oh, you want them to appear on the same page? You didn't say that. Then you need to put all the code in one view. Just create both lists and pass them both to your context.

Comment: I tried putting them under one `csv_simple_read(request)`, but nothing happened.

Comment: Show us that, because the code you're showing now is for two different views (i.e. different pages).

Comment: This. Maybe the problem is in `file2 = lite.connect("D:/clear2/VM2/chat.db")`?

Comment: But you're doing `return` before the line `file2 = ...`. When you `return` the function ends so none of the lines after it will ever be executed. Please do a python tutorial and learn python properly.

Comment: Lol. I'm ashamed of my inattention. Thank you very much. Learn a lot. You are the best!     

`return render(request, "blog/index.html", {'results': resultlist, 'results2': resultlist2})`